# How to really test the backend and avoid the use of MockWS?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am fairly new to Playframework (and Scala in general). At the moment I am writing specs2 unit test that test python backend service, using MockWS. Yes, I found it great to test whether my frontend works using the same output as what the backend generated. But what if I really want to test the backend? How can I avoid the use of MockWS?

```
"SomeService" should {
object Props {
  object Urls {
    val BaseUrl = "http://localhost:9002/someservice/"
    val Test = s"${BaseUrl}test"
  }
  val test = Test(value=true)
}

class NormalContext extends Scope {
  val ws = MockWS {
    case (GET, Props.Urls.Test) => Action {
      Ok(Json.toJson(Props.test))
    }
  }

  val abtestService = new SomeService(ws, Props.Urls.BaseUrl, 100)
}

"test mock" should {
  "return True" when {
    "call without any argument" in new NormalContext {
      val result = someService.getTest()
      whenReady(result) { result =>
        result must equal (true)
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I try to introduce this new context, but got the exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`

Any suggestion?

```
  class LiveBackEndContext extends Scope {
  import play.api.Play.current
  val ws: WSClient = WS.client
  val abtestService = new AbTestService(ws, Props.Urls.BaseUrl, 100)
}
  "test without mock" should {
  "return True" when {
    "call without any argument" in new LiveBackEndContext {
      val result = abtestService.getTest()
      whenReady(result) { result =>
        result must equal (true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```